# How can I parse an XML Feed from WordPress from using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to parse and load an XML (from WordPress) from the same domain  but I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.knead-nyc.com/articles/feed/. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

What's strange is that my html page is located here:
http://knead-nyc.com/test.html
and my WordPress xml feed is here: http://www.knead-nyc.com/articles/feed/

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Document</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function parse(document){
            $(document).find("item").each(function(){
                $("#content").append(
                    '<br /> Title: '+$(this).find('title').text()+
                    '<br /> Author: '+$(this).find('link').text()+
                    '</p>'
                );
            });
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.knead-nyc.com/articles/feed/', // name of file you want to parse
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parse,
            error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I installed WordPress in the "articles" folder. In order to prevent domain conflict I made the following changes to the `.htaccess` file located in the WordPress root directory but it's not working:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /articles/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /articles/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of searching and found a solution. Although I was on the same domain (example.com) I was getting the following error. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.org/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://www.example.org is therefore not allowed access"

I found out that occasionally, the same origin policy may block requests between sub-domains on the same domain. So after a few searches I was able to solve this problem by by adding document.domain within my JavaScript. For example:
    document.domain = 'example.com';

I also changed the top portion of my JavaScript to:

```
$("#loading").show();
                    document.domain = 'example.com'; 
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/articles/feed/",
            //url will load http://www.example.com/articles/feed/
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: parseXml
});
```